# Add Glyphicon to Table Row Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, glyphicons

I have a html table on my website that is displaying a live feed of data. I am retrieving this using a combination of PHP, MySQL and AJAX.

Table rows are being added to the table as new data is retrieved. Everything is working as expected.

I would like to add a glyphicon to a `<td>` depending on the contents of a javascript variable.

My html table is as follows;

```
<table id="transactionTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date / Time</th>
            <th>Card No</th>
            <th>Direction</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The jquery that adds rows to the table;

```
$("#transactionTable").prepend('<tr><td>'+data.SerialNo+'</td><td>'+dateFormatted+'</td><td>'+data.CardNo+'</td><td id="direction">'+data.Direction+'</td></tr>');
```

What I want to do is,

```
// data.Direction is coming from the server

if(data.Direction == 'I') {
    // add <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span>
 }
if(data.Direction == 'O') {
    // <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>
}
```

So the table rows should look like;

```
// if(data.Direction == 'I')
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>News</td>
    <td>News Cate</td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span> In</td>
</tr>
```

Or;

```
// if(data.Direction == 'O')
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>News</td>
    <td>News Cate</td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> In</td>
</tr>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine which icon you want to display, store it in a variable and add it to your the string you are passing into the prepend method.

```
var iconHtml = '';

if (data.Direction == 'I') {
    iconHtml = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span> ';
}
if (data.Direction === 'O') {
    iconHtml = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> ';
}

$("#transactionTable").prepend('<tr><td>' + data.SerialNo +'</td><td>'+dateFormatted+'</td><td>'+data.CardNo+'</td><td id="direction">' + iconHtml +data.Direction+'</td></tr>');
```

```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is one of way doing it: we're creating a variable that will be set to the correct icon class, depending on the direction.

```
var directionIcon;

// Decide which icon class should be used depending on the data.Direction
if(data.Direction == 'I') directionIcon = 'glyphicon-import';
else if(data.Direction == 'O') directionIcon = 'glyphicon-export';
```

Now that we have the class name of the icon, we can create the span element.

```
// Create the span using the correct icon
directionIcon = '<span class="glyphicon ' + directionIcon + '"></span>';
```

That's basically it. Now all we need to do is use this when we're creating the row.

```
// Create table row, including the icon before direction
$("#transactionTable").prepend('<tr><td>'+data.SerialNo+'</td><td>'+dateFormatted+'</td><td>'+data.CardNo+'</td><td id="direction">'+ directionIcon + ' ' + data.Direction+'</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `data.Direction` always present, and does it always equal either `I` or `O`? If so, this is a slightly more condensed version of the other answers:

```
var iconSuffix = data.Direction == "I" ? "import" : "export";
$("#transactionTable").prepend('<tr><td>'+data.SerialNo+'</td><td>'+data.dateFormatted+'</td><td>'+data.CardNo+'</td><td id="direction"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-'+iconSuffix+'"></span>'+data.Direction+'</td></tr>');
```